# Answer received after the question marked as duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558300/which-collection-is-the-best-way-to-get-value-from-list-which-contains-key-value), which got marked a duplicate and 3 minutes after that it received an answer on it. How it that possible. Is this some kind of bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as a demonstration, this was started *after* I already cast the final close-vote.
Just look at the time.

Comment: Witchcraft and blasphemy this is.

Comment: [From this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91928/304763), how did you skip the client side restriction? Because couple of time it happened that I was writing the answer and question got closed.

Comment: @TinyGiant Call for the mob coming with torches and pitchforks ;-) ...

Comment: @TinyGiant has it right. The answer is that it's client-side and thus under your exclusive control, and I only did it here for the meta-fun. Posting a recipe is *not a good idea*.